# Realm crashes with error: "Configurations cannot be different if used to open the same file." with a SyncConfiguration

Tags: java, realm

In the onSuccess block after signing in, I'm initializing my realm configurations then creating a User object.

```
    if (SyncUser.currentUser() != null) {
        RealmConfig.form = new SyncConfiguration.Builder(SyncUser.currentUser(), getString(R.string.form)).name("form.realm").build();
        RealmConfig.user = new SyncConfiguration.Builder(SyncUser.currentUser(), getString(R.string.user)).name("user.realm").build();
        RealmConfig.userObjects = new SyncConfiguration.Builder(SyncUser.currentUser(), getString(R.string.user_objects))
                .name("userObjects.realm")
                .waitForInitialRemoteData()
                .build();
    }

    Realm.getInstanceAsync(RealmConfig.userObjects, new Realm.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Realm realm) {
            User user = realm.where(User.class).equalTo("id",
                    SyncUser.currentUser().getIdentity()).findFirst();

            if (user == null) {
                realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(Realm realm) {
                        User user = realm.createObject(User.class, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                        user.setEmail(mEmailView.getText().toString().trim());
                    }
                });
                // go to CreateUserName
            } else {
                // go to Dashboard
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("isAdmin", isAdmin);
                getBaseContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
```

I cannot open the instance I want to create the user because of this crash...additionally I am getting an error saying "RealmException: Exception happens when initializing Realm in the background thread."

Answer (score 0):

WOW. Ok so the whole time I was hitting "Enter" on my laptop's keyboard and it was calling the login function twice in rapid succession and that must've been screwing it up. I clicked the "Sign In" button on the actual screen and it worked without issues.

Sometimes there's just nobody to blame but yourself...